# Laravel 6.0 does not support DELETE, PUT methods

Tags: php, laravel, forms, laravel-6

I have a package what I made at Laravel 5.8. When I installed it in a new project with Laravel 6.0, DELETE and PUT methods returned an error.

> The DELETE method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD, POST.

When I wrote at composer.json Laravel 5.8 and reinstalled composer -- it worked. So trouble at version.

Also, this shows me all my routes.

```
php artisan route:list
```

I use resource routes like:

```php
Route::resource('langs', 'Sashaef\TranslateProvider\Controllers\LangsController');
```

**Form**

```php
<form id="myForm" action="{{ route('langs.update', [ 'id' => 0 ]) }}"
      method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT"/>
```

Comment: post the output of `php artisan route:list`

Comment: does using `@csrf` instead of `csrf_field()`, `@method('PUT')` or `@method('DELETE')` instead of the hidden _method field change anything? Also, the resulting routes generated from `Route::resource(...)` should expect a `lang` parameter, not an `id` parameter. Try `route('langs.update', ['lang' => 0])`

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure this is caused by how you call the route.

```php
Route::resource('langs', 'xController');
```

Should generate the following update route

```php
Methods:PUT|PATCH
Uri:    langs/{lang}
Name:   langs.update
```

You can verify this by running `php artisan r:l --name=langs.update`

You're also calling it wrong

```
# WRONG WAY
route('langs.update', ['id' => 0])   // yields: /langs?id=0
# RIGHT WAY
route('langs.update', ['lang' => 0]) // yields: /langs/0
```

You can verify this in a tinker session

Comment: Thanks, this was helpful. I found that this is actually documented in the [upgrade guide](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/upgrade) under "Route URL Generation & Extra Parameters". The `The DELETE method is not supported` message only shows up because it can't find the right route to match with, due to the parameter binding changes.